# How do i find the sum of a range of random numbers in python?

Tags: python, function, random, integer, range

```
import random

def randnums():
    for count in range(6):
        number = random.randint(1,9)
        print(number)

randnums()
```

---

From here I am supposed to add the 6 random numbers and display their total... Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your completed homework:

```
import random

def randnums():
   numbers = [] 
   for count in range(6):
        number = random.randint(1,9)
        numbers.append(number)
        print(number)
   print(sum(numbers))
randnums()
```

Comment: Why bother with a list when you can just keep a running total?

Comment: @SirParselot You are correct that either way works. I only did it that way as in most cases where I would do something similar, I end up needing the original values later on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just print the numbers: accumulate them in a list.  Then use the built-in **sum** function to add the entire list.

For your own efficiency, please get used to searching the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and on-line tutorials for help on language mechanics and tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep a running total of the random numbers rather than storing them in a list and then calling `sum()` on it. Using a list consumes more memory but is useful if you need to access the numbers later on.

```
import random

def randnums():
    total=0
    for count in range(6):
        number = random.randint(1,9)
        total+=number
    print(total)

randnums()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import random

    a = random.sample(range(1, 12), 8)  # generate your random array of numbers

    print a    #print the array to visualize the numbers generated

    print sum (a)
```